# Prevent eclipse warnings in imported ant build script

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a build script defining most of the targets and relevant properties in there.

Now I had to add another target for a very special purpose. As the initial build script was already quite long, I decided to define the new target in a new included script file:

The original build script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project" default="jar">
    <!-- property and path definitions -->
    <path id="compile-classpath">
        <!-- path elements here -->
    </path>
    <!-- targets -->
    <target name="init">
         <!-- do stuff -->
    </target>
    <import file="additional.xml" />
</project>
```

The imported build script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="macker">
    <!-- custom properties -->
    <path id="macker.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${qisserver-webinf}/internal/macker" 
                 includes="**/*.jar" />
        <path refid="compile-classpath" />
    </path>
    <taskdef name="macker" 
             classname="net.innig.macker.ant.MackerAntTask" 
             classpathref="macker.classpath" />
    <!-- targets -->
    <target name="macker-report">
        <!-- Do macker reporting -->
    </target>
</project>
```

Now eclipse produces a warning in the line with the taskdef complaining about not being able to find the referenced path "compile-classpath", which is originally defined in the original build script shown above.

How can I fix this while keeping this structure?

Comment: Where is "compile-classpath" defined in the original build script?

Comment: Updated my question with an added path definition as in the original build script.